# Android, retrieve authenticated users information from azure table

Tags: java, android, json, azure

I have a custom login and registration set up with my app. The users information is stored on a table on the Azure platform. When a user logs in successfully they are authenticated. Here is the function I created to login and authenticate users:

```
mAuthService.login(mTxtEmail.getText().toString(), mTxtPassword.getText().toString(), new TableJsonOperationCallback() {
                @Override
                public void onCompleted(JsonObject jsonObject, Exception exception,
                                        ServiceFilterResponse response) {
                    if (exception == null) {
                        //If they've registered successfully, we'll save and set the userdata and then
                        //show the logged in activity
                        mAuthService.setUserAndSaveData(jsonObject);
                        String email = mTxtEmail.getText().toString();
                        Intent loggedInIntent = new Intent(mActivity, UserNeighborhoodLogin.class);
                        loggedInIntent.putExtra("UserLoginEmail", email);
                        startActivity(loggedInIntent);
                    } else {
                        Log.e(TAG, "Error loggin in: " + exception.getMessage());
                    }
                }
            });
```

So the users information is sent to a class called AuthService as a json object on this line:

```
mAuthService.setUserAndSaveData(jsonObject);
```

I am wondering, once a user is logged in,  how could I call this json object from within any class in my project in order to obtain and use the users information?

Here is the bulk of the AuthService file which takes care of login and authentication:

```
public class AuthService extends Activity {
    private MobileServiceClient mClient;
    private MobileServiceJsonTable mTableAccounts;
    private MobileServiceJsonTable mTableAuthData;
    private MobileServiceJsonTable mTableBadAuth;
    private Context mContext;
    private final String TAG = "AuthService";
    private boolean mShouldRetryAuth;
    private boolean mIsCustomAuthProvider = false;
    private MobileServiceAuthenticationProvider mProvider;
    private ProgressBar mProgressBar;

    public AuthService(Context context) {
        mContext = context;
        try {
            mClient = new MobileServiceClient("https://smartneighborhoodwatch.azure-mobile.net/",
                    "iYkvhkWHEsIcBuVkpBqznTqhFQhxOp89", mContext)
                    .withFilter(new ProgressFilter());
            mTableAccounts = mClient.getTable("Accounts");
            mTableAuthData = mClient.getTable("AuthData");
            mTableBadAuth = mClient.getTable("BadAuth");
        } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
            Log.e(TAG, "There was an error creating the Mobile Service.  Verify the URL");
        }
    }

    public void setContext(Context context) {
        mClient.setContext(context);
    }

    public String getUserId() {
        return mClient.getCurrentUser().getUserId();
    }

    //Show the login dialog
    public void login(Context activityContext, MobileServiceAuthenticationProvider provider, UserAuthenticationCallback callback) {
        mProvider = provider;
        mClient.setContext(activityContext);
        mClient.login(provider, callback);
    }

    /**
     * Handles logging in with custom auth
     * @param email
     * @param password
     * @param callback
     */
    public void login(String email, String password, TableJsonOperationCallback callback) {
        JsonObject customUser = new JsonObject();
        customUser.addProperty("email", email);
        customUser.addProperty("password", password);

        List<Pair<String,String>> parameters = new ArrayList<Pair<String, String>>();
        parameters.add(new Pair<String, String>("login", "true"));

        mTableAccounts.insert(customUser, parameters, callback);
    }

    public void getAuthData(TableJsonQueryCallback callback) {
        mTableAuthData.where().execute(callback);
    }

    /**
     * Checks to see if we have userId and token stored on the device and sets them if so
     * @return
     */
    public boolean isUserAuthenticated() {
        SharedPreferences settings = mContext.getSharedPreferences("UserData", 0);
        if (settings != null) {
            String userId = settings.getString("userid", null);
            String token = settings.getString("token", null);
            if (userId != null && !userId.equals("")) {
                setUserData(userId, token);
                return true;
            }
        }
        return false;
    }

    /**
     * Creates a nwe MobileServiceUser using a userId and token passed in.
     * Also sets the current provider
     * @param userId
     * @param token
     */
    public void setUserData(String userId, String token) {
        MobileServiceUser user = new MobileServiceUser(userId);
        user.setAuthenticationToken(token);
        mClient.setCurrentUser(user);

        //Check for custom provider
        String provider = userId.substring(0, userId.indexOf(":"));
        if (provider.equals("Custom")) {
            mProvider = null;
            mIsCustomAuthProvider = true;
        } else if (provider.equals("Facebook"))
            mProvider = MobileServiceAuthenticationProvider.Facebook;
        else if (provider.equals("Twitter"))
            mProvider = MobileServiceAuthenticationProvider.Twitter;
        else if (provider.equals("MicrosoftAccount"))
            mProvider = MobileServiceAuthenticationProvider.MicrosoftAccount;
        else if (provider.equals("Google"))
            mProvider = MobileServiceAuthenticationProvider.Google;
    }

    /***
     * Pulls the user ID and token out of a json object from the server
     * @param jsonObject
     */
    public void setUserAndSaveData(JsonObject jsonObject) {
        String userId = jsonObject.getAsJsonPrimitive("userId").getAsString();
        String token = jsonObject.getAsJsonPrimitive("token").getAsString();
        setUserData(userId, token);
        saveUserData();
    }

    /**
     * Saves userId and token to SharedPreferences.
     * NOTE:  This is not secure and is just used as a storage mechanism.  In reality, you would want to
     * come up with a more secure way of storing this information.
     */
    public void saveUserData() {
        SharedPreferences settings = mContext.getSharedPreferences("UserData", 0);
        SharedPreferences.Editor preferencesEditor = settings.edit();
        preferencesEditor.putString("userid", mClient.getCurrentUser().getUserId());
        preferencesEditor.putString("token", mClient.getCurrentUser().getAuthenticationToken());
        preferencesEditor.commit();
    }


    public void registerUser(String password, String confirm, String username,
                             String neighbourhood, String membership, String email,
                             TableJsonOperationCallback callback) {
        JsonObject newUser = new JsonObject();
        newUser.addProperty("password", password);
        newUser.addProperty("username", username);
        newUser.addProperty("neighbourhood", neighbourhood);
        newUser.addProperty("membership", membership);
        newUser.addProperty("email", email);
        mTableAccounts.insert(newUser, callback);
    }

    /**
     * Handles logging the user out including:
     * -deleting cookies so their login with a provider won't be cached in the web view
     * -removing the userdata from the shared preferences
     * -setting the current user object on the client to logged out
     * -optionally redirects to the login page if requested
     * @param shouldRedirectToLogin
     */
    public void logout(boolean shouldRedirectToLogin) {
        //Clear the cookies so they won't auto login to a provider again
        CookieSyncManager.createInstance(mContext);
        CookieManager cookieManager = CookieManager.getInstance();
        cookieManager.removeAllCookie();
        //Clear the user id and token from the shared preferences
        SharedPreferences settings = mContext.getSharedPreferences("UserData", 0);
        SharedPreferences.Editor preferencesEditor = settings.edit();
        preferencesEditor.clear();
        preferencesEditor.commit();
        //Clear the user and return to the auth activity
        mClient.logout();
        //Take the user back to the auth activity to relogin if requested
        if (shouldRedirectToLogin) {
            Intent logoutIntent = new Intent(mContext, AuthenticationActivity.class);
            logoutIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
            mContext.startActivity(logoutIntent);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

According to your source code, I think you want to retrieve the user information when a user has been logged in.

Per my experience, I think you can directly query the user information from Mobile Service table, such as the code below.

```
MobileServiceTable<User> mToDoTable = mClient.getTable("User", User.class);

new AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void>() {
    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
        try {
            final MobileServiceList<User> result = mToDoTable.where().field("userId").eq(userId).execute().get();
            for (ToDoItem item : result) {
                Log.i(TAG, "Read object with ID " + item.id);
            }
        } catch (Exception exception) {
            createAndShowDialog(exception, "Error");
        }
        return null;
    }
}.execute();
```

Please see the section [How to: Query data from a mobile service](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/mobile-services-android-how-to-use-client-library/#querying) of the offical doc to know.